# How to decode a Base64 string?

Tags: powershell, base64

I have a normal string in Powershell that is from a text file containing Base64 text; it is stored in `$x`. I am trying to decode it as such:

```
$z = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($x));
```

This works if `$x` was a Base64 string created in Powershell (but it's not). And this does not work on the `$x` Base64 string that came from a file, `$z` simply ends up as something like `䐲券`.

What am I missing? For example, `$x` could be `YmxhaGJsYWg=` which is Base64 for `blahblah`.

In a nutshell, `YmxhaGJsYWg=` is in a text file then put into a string in this Powershell code and I try to decode it but end up with `䐲券` etc.

Comment: Base64-encoded strings will always be longer than the original data. You appear to have something backwards here.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Oops, updated.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Isn't encoding taking the text TO base64 and decoding taking base64 BACK to text? You seem be mixing them up here. When I decode using [this online decoder](http://www.base64decode.org/) I get:

```
BASE64: blahblah
UTF8: nVnV
```

not the other way around. I can't reproduce it completely in PS though. See sample below:

```
PS > [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("blahblah"))
nV�nV�

PS > [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("nVnV"))
blZuVg==
```

**EDIT** I believe you're using the wrong encoder for your text. The encoded base64 string is encoded from UTF8(or ASCII) string.

```
PS > [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("YmxhaGJsYWg="))
blahblah

PS > [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("YmxhaGJsYWg="))
汢桡汢桡

PS > [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("YmxhaGJsYWg="))
blahblah
```

Comment: I already have an encoded string `nVnV` and I'm trying to decode it. That seems backwards to me, "blahblah" is the human readable string I need and "nVnV" is the encoded string I need to decode.

Comment: see updated answer. I can't reproduce it, but I can't figure out how you got "nVnV" (base64) from "blahblah".

Comment: I updated my OP, sorry. Yes, I can do it in 100% Powershell but that's not what I'm doing. The Base64 is coming from a text file.

Answer (score 49):

There are ***no* PowerShell-native commands for Base64 conversion - yet** (as of PowerShell [Core] 7.1), but adding  dedicated cmdlets has been suggested in [GitHub issue #8620](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8620).
For now, direct use of .NET is needed.

**Important**:

- [Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is **an encoding of *binary* data** using *bytes* whose values are constrained to a well-defined 64-character *subrange* of the ASCII character set representing *printable characters*, devised at a time when sending arbitrary bytes was problematic, especially with the high bit set (byte values > 0x7f).
- Therefore, **you must always specify *explicitly* what *character encoding* the Base64 bytes do / should represent**.

Ergo:

- on **converting TO Base64**, you must first **obtain a *byte representation*** of the string you're trying to encode using the character encoding the *consumer* of the Base64 string expects.
- on **converting FROM Base64**, you must **interpret the resultant array of bytes as a string** *using the same encoding that was used to create the Base64 representation*.

**Examples:**

Note:

- The following examples convert to and from *UTF-8* encoded strings:
- To convert to and from *UTF-16LE* ("Unicode") instead, substitute `[Text.Encoding]::Unicode` for `[Text.Encoding]::UTF8`

**Convert TO Base64:**

```
PS> [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('Motörhead'))
TW90w7ZyaGVhZA==
```

**Convert FROM Base64:**

```
PS> [Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String('TW90w7ZyaGVhZA=='))
Motörhead
```

Answer (score 14):

If anyone would like to do it with a pipe in Powershell (like a filter) (e.g. read file contents and decode it), it can be achieved with a one-liner like that:

`Get-Content base64.txt | %{[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($_))}`

Answer (score 12):

This page shows up when you google how to convert to base64, so for completeness:

```
$b  = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("blahblah")
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($b)
```

Answer (score 6):

I had issues with spaces showing in between my output and there was no answer online at all to fix this issue. I literally spend many hours trying to find a solution and found one from playing around with the code to the point that I almost did not even know what I typed in at the time that I got it to work. Here is my fix for the issue: `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString(([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64string)|?{$_}))`

Answer (score 5):

Base64 encoding converts three 8-bit bytes (0-255) into four 6-bit bytes (0-63 aka base64). Each of the four bytes indexes an ASCII string which represents the final output as four 8-bit ASCII characters. The indexed string is typically 'A-Za-z0-9+/' with '=' used as padding. This is why encoded data is 4/3 longer.

Base64 decoding is the inverse process. And as one would expect, the decoded data is 3/4 as long.

While base64 encoding can encode plain text, its real benefit is encoding non-printable characters which may be interpreted by transmitting systems as control characters.

I suggest the original poster render $z as bytes with each bit having meaning to the application. Rendering non-printable characters as text typically invokes Unicode which produces glyphs based on your system's localization.

Base64decode("the answer to life the universe and everything") = 00101010

Answer (score 2):

Still not a "built-in", but published to gallery, authored by MS:

https://github.com/powershell/textutility

## TextUtility

- ConvertFrom-Base64
  Return a string decoded from base64.
- ConvertTo-Base64
  Return a base64 encoded representation of a string.

Comment: found via https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8620

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.TextUtility