# converting a variable to a byte without using Get-content

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I need to convert the $var to a byte array to push it to `[convert]::ToBase64String($var)` for upload to a sql DB.  All without using Get-Content -file -encoding Byte, as this script is running in Azure without access to any filesystem.

Header contains Auuth bearer token.

```
$var = (invoke-restmethod -uri ...800x800.png -method -get -headers $head)
```

Data stream looks like this:

PNG

IHDR         Ûph   gAMA  ±üa    cHRM  z&    ú   è  u0  ê`  :  pºQ<   bKGD ÿ ÿ ÿ ½§   tIMEã
     5Þ   IDATxÚìý[°e[}ß?Æ\kgÌçä¹:UÝÕ¥Ôh!]@Rè ÆÌÕ°ÍÃ?øÁðà'¿áðG¶#ÆÆ1!ä ²
...

```
 [System.Array]$myarray = (invoke-restmethod...
 $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($myarray)
 $encoded_array = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

Upon decoding of the base64 string, it is sensed as a application/octet instead of an image octet and is broken.

However, running the usual

```
invoke-restmethod ... ... -outfile c:\test.png
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String (get-content c\test.png -encoding byte)
```

works, as it should.

To reproduce:

```
(invoke-restmethod -uri "URI to .png" -method -get )
```

then play with it till you can get it into an encoded base 64 string.

Wanted result is a base64 string that is the image.
Current result is a base 64 string that is ???  and isn't decoded into anything useful.

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414678/how-to-decode-a-base64-string , I am assuming you must be using the wrong encoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following code to convert image to byte64:

1.

```
$file='C:\aaa.png'
$strm=([io.FileInfo]$file).OpenRead()
$bytes=New-Object byte[] $strm.Length
$strm.Read($bytes,0,$strm.Length)
$base64String=[convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$base64String
```

2.

```
$url='C:\aaa.png' or 'https://xxx/aaa.png'
$wc=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$bytes=$wc.DownloadData($url)
$base64String1=[convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$base64String1
```

3.

```
$url='C:\aaa.png' or 'https://xxx/aaa.png'
$bytes = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
$base64String2=[convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$base64String2
```

Then go to this [link](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter#) you could successfully convert byte64 to image.

Comment: Great code,  i had found the 2nd answer independently.  
But now my question is:
What exactly is the .net.WebClient and besides the obvious, how is it different than the invoke-restmethod?

It almost seems that I should be using .net.webclient instead of Invoke-RestMethod to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer by using these commands:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer <token>"
$bytes = $wc.DownloadData("URL")
$base64string = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```